# High power power regulators - thyristor regulator?

Tags: power, automation, thyristor, industrial

I am currently working on a system design that intends to control heating in different zones. All zones in total is calculated to use approx 340kW (230V). This will be divided into 11-12 smaller distributions. One distribution equals one zone, and each will maximum have 45kW.

The whole system will be controlled by a PLC and turn on/off the heating according to temperature, wind, humidity etc.

To regulate the effect of this I first thought of contactors, but I do not believe they will keep up in the long run (breaking due to too many cycles). I then came across the thyristor regulator, and as I have no experience with this, I wonder if it's the right thing in this setting? Even so, how long could I expect this component to last?

The system is designed for harsh enviroments and must be able to run with little/no service.

Comment: Thyristors have no definite life span, but when they go, they tend to go short. Cycling them thermally reduces the life in practice. Phase control will cause possibly (probably) problematic EMI, but less thermal cycling. Suggest thyristor on/off switching with backup electromechanical contactors. Save yourself hassles and buy approved SCR power control packs unless you've got some reason not to (and follow the mfrs instructions).

Comment: Can you define the characteristics of your heating load?  Is the Heat load resistive heat elements or something more like heat pumps?

Comment: It's resistive heat elements.

Answer (score 1):

350kW? so you will have 3phase input

One option you could use is in-line thyristors

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fmpjs0.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

How to control?
You could do a simple BANG-BANG & fire all 6 SCR when the temperature falls too low & turn them all off when it gets too high.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fMCkxA.png)</sup>

This might be adequate BUT with a high pulse in output power. A bit more work and you can do phase-control on the firing of the SCR. This will reduce the power driven to the heater to then provide a smoother temperature control

One thing worth noting!  you are dealing with 350kW & there is going to be a large power quality consideration to worry about ( you will be charged in VA & have a tight power quality profile to match).

While phase control will give you a nicer temperature response it does mean you will need to think about the AC side draw a bit.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, and sorry for my late reply.  It's not the plan to power on/off 350kW all at one time. The intention is to control each of the 11 zones (each zone will maximum be 45kW) independently.  For example would one zone be exposed to wind and snow while the other zones are not, then the first zone would need different regulation then the others.  


I have looked at Eurotherm products from Schneider Electric for this purpose.